# Configure MemProtect to allow access only by a specific app

Tags: memory, configuration

I have a little problem with Excubits MemProtect.

I want to configure the driver like this:

The memory of my_process.exe could be modified only by admin.exe.

I tried smthing like this but no result:

```html
[#INSTALLMODE]
[LETHAL]
[LOGGING]
[WHITELIST]
*>*
!admin.exe>my_process.exe
[BLACKLIST]
*>*my_process.exe
[EOF]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is simple, just place the rule

!admin.exe>my_process.exe before the generic rule

*>*

The manual states, that priority rules shall be fore any generic rules using * or ?.

Cheers!

So, your config should look like:

```
[#INSTALLMODE]
[LETHAL]
[LOGGING]
[WHITELIST]
!admin.exe>my_process.exe
*>*
[BLACKLIST]
*>*my_process.exe
[EOF]
```